# Cannot access civicrm/report/list

Tags: drupal, permissions

As an administrator i go to

```
 Contributions > Contribution reports
```

but I am getting an error: access not allowed

In the Drupal log:

```
cannot access civicrm/report/list
```

In the CiviCRM log:

```
Jan 06 17:00:24  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [message] =>  is not of type String
    [code] => 
)

Jan 06 17:00:24  [info] $backTrace = #0 <path_to_civicrm>/CRM/Core/Error.php(331): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 <path_to_civicrm>/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1399): CRM_Core_Error::fatal(" is not of type String")
#2 <path_to_civicrm>/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1284): CRM_Core_DAO::composeQuery("\nSELECT v.id, v.label, v.value, v.name, v.weight, v.description\nFROM   civi...", (Array:2), TRUE)
#3 <path_to_civicrm>/CRM/Core/OptionGroup.php(602): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("\nSELECT v.id, v.label, v.value, v.name, v.weight, v.description\nFROM   civi...", (Array:2))
#4 <path_to_civicrm>/CRM/Report/Utils/Report.php(423): CRM_Core_OptionGroup::getRowValues("report_template", NULL, "value")
#5 <path_to_civicrm>/api/v3/Job.php(224): CRM_Report_Utils_Report::processReport((Array:3))
#6 <path_to_civicrm>/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_job_mail_report((Array:3))
#7 <path_to_civicrm>/Civi/API/Kernel.php(161): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:9))
#8 <path_to_civicrm>/Civi/API/Kernel.php(92): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest((Array:7))
#9 <path_to_civicrm>/api/api.php(23): Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe("job", "mail_report", (Array:3), NULL)
#10 <path_to_civicrm>/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(134): civicrm_api("job", "mail_report", (Array:3))
#11 <path_to_civicrm>/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(79): CRM_Core_JobManager->executeJob(Object(CRM_Core_ScheduledJob))
#12 <path_to_civicrm>/CRM/Utils/System.php(1691): CRM_Core_JobManager->execute(FALSE)
#13 [internal function](): CRM_Utils_System::executeScheduledJobs()
#14 <path_to_civicrm>/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(276): call_user_func((Array:2))
#15 <path_to_civicrm>/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:12))
#16 <path_to_civicrm>/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#17 <path_to_civicrm>/drupal/civicrm.module(448): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#18 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("admin", "runjobs")
#19 /home/<account_name>/public_html/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))
#20 /home/<account_name>/public_html/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#21 {main}
```

As an administrator i should have full access, but i do not see the place where i can check (or change) this "full access", nor allowing myself to access report/list.

Thanks for all information and help!

Comment: Can you fill in more details i.e version, screenshot etc ? Do you see any backtrace in civi log file `sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/<file_name>.log`?

Comment: @jitendrapurchit, thx for reply. This backtrace is in the log file:

Jan 06 17:00:24  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [message] =>  is not of type String
    [code] => 
)


Jan 06 17:00:24  [info] $backTrace = #0 /home/<account_name>/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(331): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 ...

(continues to #21, but cannot be posted here...)

Comment: So can you update the question with the backtrace, civi version ?

Comment: @jitendrapurchit

mysql/mariadb 5.6.34-log
php 5.6.29
drupal 7.53
civicrm 4.7.14

Comment: Can you paste the backtrace in the question ?

Comment: The backtrace is about scheduled jobs and a mail report - not contribution reports so looks like two separate things although may be related.

Comment: @Aidan Then where to find the error logging of (what seems to be) the CiviReport problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `/admin/people/permissions` and look for the CiviReport permissions.

Comment: no CiviReport in the list of permissions

Comment: Then check the Reports component is enabled at `/civicrm/admin/setting/component`

Comment: Aidan, I have done so, and it works now. Error message was pointing to a permission problem, while it seems to be a component disabled problem! What a waste of time to finally discover that the error message was... erroneous :(